# How to search while we type in Eclipse Mars?

Tags: search, find, eclipse-mars

How to search while we type in Eclipse Mars? For example if we want to search something in Java file it Eclipse should highlight text as we are typing string to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'Edit > Incremental Find Next' and start typing the string to find.

The is normal bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Macs)